# How to write redirection rule in .htaccess using Regex

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

can someone tell me how to write redirection rule using regex in .htaccess file.
I want

```
www.example.com/healthcare/practitioner/nikky.23
```

to be redirectd to

```
www.example.com/healthcare/practitioner/#/nikky.23
```

Note that last parameter after '/' i.e nikky.23 can change in different cases.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule (healthcare/practitioner/).* $1
```

If you want the last parameter to be without further slashes:

```
RewriteRule (healthcare/practitioner/)[^/]*$ $1
```

Comment: @Alex did you set `RewriteEngine on` and `RewriteBase /`?

Comment: Oh, maybe there is an infinite looping. Try using `+` quantifier instead of `*`.